# success_url not working with url that-has/<int:pk>

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

The success_url is workin fine with a url that has-no/int:pk but does not work with a url that has /int:pk throws an error NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'read_bty'.

Views.py

```
class HBTYOrderView(BSModalCreateView):
template_name = 'accounts/modals/hairbty/create_hbty.html'
form_class = HairbtyOrderForm
success_message = 'Success: Order was created.'
success_url = reverse_lazy('read-bty')
```

Urls.py

```
    path('create_btyorder/', views.HBTYOrderView.as_view(), name='create_btyorder'),
    path('read_bty/<int:pk>', views.HBTYReadView.as_view(), name='read_bty'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change it to:

```
path('read_bty/<int:id>/', views.HBTYReadView.as_view(), name='read_bty'),
```

Comment: i had done that, but am still getting an error - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'read_bty' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['read_hairbty/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']

Comment: What is your primary key for that model? Could you post it?